# Deserializing array response with a wrapper

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm attempting to use Retrofit for communicating with an API that returns JSON arrays with a wrapper object. That is, a request to /apples.json would return the following:

```
{
    apples: [ {apple1}, {apple2}, ... ]
}
```

Retrofit appears to expect the response to be of the form:

```
[ {apple1}, {apple2}, ...]
```

Is there a simple configuration option to handle this without having to write a custom Gson deserializer?

Comment: What is the class source code, can you provide it? Will using Apples class (with internal List<Apple> work?)

Comment: @cDima absolutely, using an Apples wrapper class as you suggest is what I'm doing currently. The downside is that clients of this API will now get an ApplesWrapper back instead of List<Apple>, which seems cleaner. Maybe it's just me.

As for the source of Apple, as you can guess this is just an example. The implementation of this class shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you don't have control over the API I don't think you have any other choice than use a wrapper class. However, another suggestion: If you are using the rx-java version of the Retrofit calls you could simply append a `map` that unpacks your Apples - that way your subscribers could simply take the list and would not have to worry about the `FruitBox` wrapper class...